# how moving two turtle at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

The two turtles have to be moving at the same time so that they can maybe meet but they move one after the other and I do not known how to change that.
I have tried a lot of way but I can not achieve a good result

[first part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Fm3.png)
[second and last part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQPhs.png)

thanks you for your answers.

```
import turtle as ka              
kame=ka.Turtle("turtle")          
schildkröte=ka.Turtle("turtle")   
kame.pensize(3)                  
schildkröte.pensize(3)          
kame.speed(1)
schildkröte.speed(1)
kame.setposition(-200,0)      
kame.setposition(-200,200)      
kame.setposition(200,200)            
kame.setposition(200,0)              
kame.home()                         
import random                       
import math
def is_collided_with(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 10 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 10
def reset():
    kame.penup()
    kame.setposition(random.randint(-50, 50), random.randint(0, 50))
    kame.pendown()
def reset2():
    schildkröte.penup()
    schildkröte.setposition(random.randint(-50, 50), random.randint(0, 50))
    schildkröte.pendown()
    while c:
        x,r=random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200)
        y,s=random.randint(0,200),random.randint(0,200)
        w,u=random.choice([-200,200,6]),random.choice([-200,200,6])
        z,v=random.choice([0,200]),random.choice([0,200])
        k,l=random.choice(["red","blue","green"]),random.choice(["cyan","pink","yellow"])
        if w!=6:
            if u!=6:
                kame.pencolor(k),schildkröte.pencolor(l)
                kame.penup(),schildkröte.penup()
                kame.setposition(x,y),schildkröte.setposition(r,s)
                kame.pendown(),schildkröte.pendown()
                kame.setposition(w,y),schildkröte.setposition(u,s)
                kame.undo(),schildkröte.undo()
               if is_collided_with(kame, schildkröte):
                    print('Collision!')
                    print('aaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh')
                    reset()
                    reset2()
            else:
                kame.pencolor(k),schildkröte.pencolor(l)
                kame.penup(),schildkröte.penup()
                kame.setposition(x,y),schildkröte.setposition(r,s)
                kame.pendown(),schildkröte.pendown()
                kame.setposition(w,y),schildkröte.setposition(r,v)
                kame.undo(),schildkröte.undo()
                if is_collided_with(kame, schildkröte):
                    print('Collision!')
                    print('aaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh')
                    reset()
                    reset2()
```

Comment: Do you really think anybody here wants to retype your code to solve your problem? Seriously? [I downvoted because link to image of code I do not want to retype](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) Reduce your code (**dont** post all of it) to some [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that lets us see the problem you face.

Comment: As for your problem - I dont know if you could execute the tutles on different threads, painting the same turtle-window, you might want to use some kind of gaming-framework instead. It might get close to looking as if if you restrain movement to few pixels for each turtle and switch fast between them

Comment: ok, I reduced it a bit.

Comment: why are you seperating different commands by a `,`  ? f.e. `kame.pencolor(k),schildkröte.pencolor(l)`

Comment: I tried to make python read the two at the same time but it didn't work. and python won't read it if don't put a        ,

Comment: python does not "process lines in parallel" if you put a , between them - you can put them on different lines as well - you are creating tuples of commands that return None and throw them away --- at least I think thats what the interpreter does with your komma separated Commands that return None.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think the closest thing to 'moving at the same time' would probably be setting the speed to 0; like so:

```
turtle.speed(0)
```

this will make the turtle so fast it appears to be moving at the same time.

hopefully, this helps.